# Como agrupar correctamente en grafica de barras - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Quisiera agrupar correctamente en un grafico de barras los diferentes rangos que edad que tengo en mis datos, para identificar el rango en el que se encuentra agrego un valor igual a 1 en el campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar la conexión con Power BI estos datos me los detecta como sumatoria ya que su tipo de datos es Número Entero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para graficar utilizo el gráfico de barras agrupadas en Power BI, la cual se visualiza de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera conseguir con este grafico de barras es que se agrupen de la siguiente manera, agregando la respectiva categoría en el eje Y.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la grafica que estoy construyendo en Power BI no se visualiza la categoría, quisiera que alguien me apoyara en saber si hay que agregar algunas nuevas medidas adicionales o es nada mas una configuración del grafico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que andas buscando es un dato asociado a una dimensión (franja de edad), de manera que esa dimensión sea la que pueda segmentar el informe o pueda ponerse como serie dentro del gráfico.

Para ello, necesitas una estructura de tablas distinta:

**Tabla 1**: Employee - Range. Esta tabla es la de hechos y contiene el empleado y la franja a la que pertenece. El valor del campo Range viene determinado por la segunda tabla.

**Tabla 2**: Range. Tabla de dimensión con todas las franjas. Esta tabla (1) se relaciona con la Tabla 1 (*).

Una vez lo tengas podrás arrastrar Range desde la Tabla 2 hacia el gráfico como  eje o leyenda. Tambén podrás tener un conteo general y agruparlo por franja.

Para hacerlo deberás ir a Power Query, duplicar la tabla, aplicar la transformación "Anular dinamización de columnas" (primero selecciona todas las columnas con los rangos), como en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado será el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes copiar o crear una nueva tabla como referencia a partir de la anterior. Eliminas todas las columnas a excepción la de atributo y eliminas duplicados. Como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez le das a Cerrar y aplicar, relacionas las dos tablas y ya tienes listo el modelo de datos de forma mucho más flexible.